# Non-functional requirement reliability measurement?

Tags: requirements

What is the measurement of the application's reliability as a non-functional requirement?

Comment: Uptime? For example 99.9% uptime means the application is reliable..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure reliability as it is linked to a bunch of different factors. Uptime can be one of them, for web apps. For other software, it can be something like the prevention of data loss under any circumstances.

You'll have to define it more exactly by breaking it down into your detailed expectations, then you can quantify values to measure against.

It is a core problem with nonfunctional requirements that you cannot measure them easily. You'll have to work around that as described above.